# Calculate p-value in python using R

Tags: python, r, statistics, rpy2, p-value

I want to calculate p-value in python using R.I am using this package rpy2.I am generating count_a and count_b on the fly,and calculate p-values along with it.
 When I run my script,python closes unexpectedly,and get this error message:

"Error: 'rho' must be an environment not NULL: detected in C-level eval
During startup - Warning message:

Abort trap: 6"

The data is below:

```
 count_a  count_b

 94       107
 109      92
 90       89
 18       13
```

Below is my code:

```
import rpy2.robjects as R
out= open(args.outfile, 'w')
binom=R.r['binom.test'](c(count_a,count_b))
P_val=binom['p.value'][0][0]
out.write(str(count_a) + '\t' + str(count_b) + '\t' + str(P_val)
out.close()
```

Any suggestions,or options to calculate p-value in python on a pair of values?

binom object is calculated:

```
Exact binomial test
```

data:  c(94L, 107L) 
number of successes = 94, number of trials = 201, p-value = 0.3974
alternative hypothesis: true probability of success is not equal to 0.5 
95 percent confidence interval: 
 0.3971286 0.5391627
sample estimates:
probability of success
0.4676617

However while extracting the p-value,I am getting this error:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rpy2/robjects/vectors.py", line 233, in **getitem**
    res = super(Vector, self).**getitem**(i)
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index

Comment: I confess that I haven't used rpy2 myself, but it looks suspicious having the R `c()` function in your code. Have you tried just `binom=R.r['binom.test'](count_a,count_b)` Exactly which line causes the error (ie, if you comment them all out and add them back in one-by-one which triggers the error?)

Comment: import rpy2.robjects as R, causes the error.

Comment: Which version R are you using? And which version of rpy2 for that matter?

Comment: R versions is  3.0.2 and rpy version is 2.3.0

Comment: Latest rpy2 in the 2.3.x series is 2.3.10.

Comment: I installed using sudo pip install rpy2.It was successfully installed.But,when I run python -m 'rpy2.tests'
rpy2 version: 2.3.0
built against R version: 3-0.2--63987
Error: 'rho' must be an environment not NULL: detected in C-level eval
During startup - Warning message:

 
Abort trap: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The problem was binom.names is a  StrVector, and does not support index, however it can be     converted to a Python list easily enough,and then extract those values.

    my_vec = R.IntVector([count_a,count_b])
    binom=R.r['binom.test'](my_vec)
    names= binom.names
    names = list(names)
    P_val= binom[names.index('p.value')][0]
```

For more clarifications,visit this blog http://telliott99.blogspot.com/2010/11/rpy-r-from-python-2.html

Answer (score 1):

It appears from [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/rpy/mailman/rpy-list/thread/5246F9F1.4090108@gmail.com/) that there may have been a problem with earlier version of rpy2 and R 3.0.2. Looks like the recommended version for R 3.0.2 is at least rpy2-2.3.8.

Comment: The latest version was installed,and the error was resolved.But I am not able to extract the p-value from the "binom" object.I am getting this error"TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an index"